# Leading zero is dropped when using ExportTo-Csv cmdlet

Tags: csv, powershell

Below is the script I am running.

The script is working fine. It is giving proper output, however it is removing leading zeros from couple of columns. Please suggest how to retain leading zero for the integer fields.

I am using

```
$res.data.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | ForEach-Object {$_.Replace('"','')} | Out-file $fileName -Force"
```

for exporting data to the CSV file. Please suggest how to retain the leading zeros (at least 2 decimal places).

```
param([int]$accountingDay = 1, [string]$outputFolder)

$server = "ADMSQL01"
$db = "cc111db"

function exec-storedprocedure($storedProcName,
        [hashtable] $parameters=@{},
        [hashtable] $outparams=@{},
        $conn) {

    function put-outputparameters($cmd, $outparams) {
        foreach ($outp in $outparams.Keys) {
            $p = $cmd.Parameters.Add("@$outp", (get-paramtype $outparams[$outp])) 
            $p.Direction=[System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output
            $p.Size=4
        }

    }
    function get-outputparameters($cmd,$outparams){
        foreach ($p in $cmd.Parameters) {
            if ($p.Direction -eq [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output) {
                $outparams[$p.ParameterName.Replace("@","")]=$p.Value
            }
        }
    }

    function get-paramtype($typename) {
        switch ($typename) {
            'uniqueidentifier' {[System.Data.SqlDbType]::UniqueIdentifier}
            'int' {[System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int}
            'xml' {[System.Data.SqlDbType]::Xml}
            'nvarchar' {[System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarchar}
            default {[System.Data.SqlDbType]::Varchar}
        }
    }

    $close = ($conn.State -eq [System.Data.ConnectionState]'Closed')
    if ($close) {
        $conn.Open()
    }

    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$conn)
    $cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'
    $cmd.CommandText = $storedProcName
    foreach ($p in $parameters.Keys) {
        $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@$p",[string]$parameters[$p]).Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Input
    }

    put-outputparameters $cmd $outparams
    $ds = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
    [Void]$da.fill($ds)
    if ($close) {
        $conn.Close()
    }
    get-outputparameters $cmd $outparams

    return @{data=$ds;outputparams=$outparams}
}

# setup the 'framework' to use PowerShell with SQL 
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

# SQL Server connection string
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = 'server=' + $server + ';integrated security=TRUE;database=' + $db 

# execute stored procedure
$res=exec-storedprocedure -storedProcName 'sp_OPTUS_summary' -parameters @{inAccountFieldValues=$null;inAccountViewID=1;inAccountLevel=4;inAccountingDay=$accountingDay;inAccountPeriod=3;inUserGroupID=2} -outparams @{} $sqlConnection  

if ($res.data.Tables.Count) {
    # store results in file
    $curYear = Get-Date -Format yyyy
    $curMonth = Get-Date -Format MMM
    $curTime = (Get-Date -Format s).Replace(':', ' ')
    $fileName = $outputFolder + '\scheduled-' + $curYear + '-' + $curMonth + '-' + $accountingDay + '-' + $curTime + '.csv'
    $res.data.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | ForEach-Object {$_.Replace('"','')} | Out-File $fileName -Force
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Integers don't have "leading zeroes". If you want to export formatted output you need to convert the respective fields to formatted strings, e.g. like this:

```
$res.data.Tables[0] |
  Select-Object FieldA, FieldB, @{n='FieldC';e={'{0:d2}' -f $_.FieldC}},
                @{n='FieldD';e={'{0:d2}' -f $_.FieldD}}, FieldE, ... |
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoType |
  ...
```